# Custom Protocol Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, protocols

I have a Protocol

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

protocol RequestProtocol: class {
    func RequestConnection(json: JSON, status: Int, Message: String)
}

class API: UIViewController {

    var delegate: RequestProtocol?
    var json: JSON = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func RequestConnection() {
        Alamofire.request(variablesClass.url).responseJSON { (response) -> Void in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                let result = response.result.value
                if response.response?.statusCode == 200 {
                    self.json = JSON(result!)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute:  {
                        self.delegate?.RequestConnection(json: self.json, status: (response.response?.statusCode)!, Message: "\(self.json["Message"])")
                    })
                } else {
                    self.json = JSON(result!)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute:  {
                        self.delegate?.RequestConnection(json: self.json, status: (response.response?.statusCode)!, Message: "\(self.json["Message"])")
                    })
                }
                break;
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have it called in my Main View

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController, RequestProtocol {

    func RequestConnection(json: JSON, status: Int, Message: String) {


        func showAlertView()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()
          var senderDelegateRequest = API()

          var receiverDelegateViewController = ViewController()


            senderDelegateRequest.delegate = receiverDelegateRequestRegistro
            senderDelegateRequest.RequestConnection()
    }


func showAlertView(){
        let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "You need to log in first", message: "To access the special features of the app you need to log in first.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Login", style: .default, handler: { (alertAction) -> Void in

        }))
        alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        present(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Why the Protocol does'nt execute the function to display the alert.

There is some way that as soon as the protocol is executed it can execute some function

Comment: FYI - `API` is a terrible name for a view controller subclass.

Comment: what is `RegistroController ` and why you set delegate to it and not `self`? And why `API` inherits  `UIViewController`?

Comment: You have to set the delegate to the class which adopts the protocol which is in almost all cases `self`. And consider that `receiverDelegateRequestRegistro` is most likely **not** the controller instance in the storyboard.

Comment: to add to @rmaddy's response: you "API" class does only business logic, so it doesn't make sense for it to inherit from the ViewController superclass. Just declare it as object: ```class ApiManager {}``` and remove all the viewController related functions.

Comment: Sorry, I new in Swift, API is only the nae of my class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `ViewController` class you are conforming to the protocol `RequestProtocol`. This means you can be the delegate of `API`. You created an instance called `receiverDelegateViewController` but this instance isn't loaded yet. You should change:

```
senderDelegateRequest.delegate = receiverDelegateRequestRegistro
```

to

```
senderDelegateRequest.delegate = self
```

And the delegate in `API` should call `RequestConnection`, not your `ViewController`.